# Settings for multiple monitors are not stored

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, laptop, display, system-settings

I am running Ubuntu 12.04. on a Lenovo Thinkpad T400. I connected an external monitor as a **second display**. The laptop stands under the external screen. The laptop has a native resolution of 1440x900 (16:10), the external monitor 1280x1024 (5:4). There are two graphic adapters: one internal *Intel GMA 4500 MHD* and an discrete *ATI* card. Currently, the integrated *Intel* is enabled.

I use the **Displays** application to arrange the position of the monitors so it look like this:

[image: Desired display configuration]

The problem:
Whenever I restart my computer the configuration gets lost. First, the displays are **mirrored** instead of **extended**. I have to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> two times to switch to **extended** mode. Second, the **Displays** settings still look like this:

[image: Diplay configuration after restart]

I know this worked once when I was running Ubuntu 10.10. I cannot tell since when it does not work. Do you know how I can permanently store the settings?

---

Sometimes when I start Ubuntu and press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> nothing happens. When I open **Displays** I and position the external screen above and press the "Apply" button nothing happens. Then, after a minute or so the settings apply suddenly. Do you know if there is a log file which could help to analyse the behavior?

Comment: Running 12.04 on a laptop with an external monitor, I too had problems making the selected config permanent, but after playing around with the hardware selection key, eventually, I kept it from going back to twinview.

Comment: Do you want one big extended display (fullscreen windows cover both monitors), or do you want 2 separate X screens (each screen has it's own panels and settings)?

Comment: @Anthony I want **one big screen** where I can move application windows from top to bottom and vice versa. The application menu and dock are available **on both screens** at the moment which is fine.

Comment: @JJD Any success?

Comment: @Anthony I currently not at my home computer and can't test it :( I will update the thread as soon as I am back.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 basic approaches you can take. The first is to utilize **randr** which will allow you to create one large virtual display in which you can position your monitors. The second is to utilize **xinerama** which will allow you to have 2 separate X screens which will function as one large display. I will cover both here and you can decide which is more appropriate for your needs.

---

**RandR** - Resize and Rotate

You can dynamically enable dual head by using **XRandR**

```
xrandr --output foo --above bar
```

There is also a gui frontend for this called **arandr** which is in the 12.04 repos, but it would seem that you want a more static configuration.

It could be as simple as creating **/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf** with the contents:

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier     "Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier     "Monitor1"
  Option         "Above" "Monitor0" 
EndSection
```

This method implies an *randr* setup. There are some notable drawbacks if using *xrandr* with monitors of different resolutions. Windows may be improperly placed, there may be black areas on one screen, etc..

When you run *xrandr* without command line options you can find out which *Identifier* you need to use in your *10-monitor.conf*. Then restart Ubuntu to see if the settings are loaded.

---

**Xinerama**
To enable xinerama you need to modify **/etc/X11/xorg.conf**:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
  Option    "Xinerama" "true"
EndSection
```

It might be as simple as that as X is pretty good about automagically configuring things based on hardware detection. But, if simply turning the *xinerama* extension on does not provide the functionality you desire, you may opt to fully configure X to use *xinerama*. There are a few ways to configure X. You could have multiple files in **/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/**, some for your monitors, some for the devices, etc. I will cover having a single *xorg.conf* file that contains all the settings using a modified version of my current setup.

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "DualHead"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" Above "Screen0"
    Option         "Xinerama" "1"                # You can specify xinerama here
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"                     # A Device section for each monitor
    Driver         "nvidia"                      # Specify the driver to use
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 430"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"                   # Use lspci | grep VGA to find BusID
    Screen          0                            # Do note the screen number
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 430"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          1                            # Do note the screen number
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Gateway HX2000"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL 1907FPV"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
EndSection
```

Obviously you will need to modify this to suit your hardware, but the basic skeleton is there for you.

Do note that I have recently read that Intel *might* have issues with *xinerama*. You may find yourself needing to utilize your discrete graphics card.

Comment: I do not have xorg.conf located anywhere in my Ubuntu 12.04 and I read that xorg.conf doesn't automatically generated anymore. Also I tried to create a new one using ' sudo xorg -configure' which returned a Fatal Error stating, server is already running for display 0 and gets terminated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work but it's worth a try: Disable the intel; enable the ati; install proprietary ati/amd drivers; configure the dual-monitor desktop how you want it; verify the configuration in the amd catalyst software (admin); check that your setup is now persistent.  I have a desktop, but using the catalyst tool was the only way I was able to keep my dual-monitor setup persistent.

Comment: I admit I cannot remember if the ATI adapter was enabled at the time it worked. Though, if possible anyhow I would like to avoid the discrete graphic card since the Intel consumes less power and does not heat up my notebook as much as the ATI does.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set the multiple monitor setting in ~/.xprofile.
For example, to set permanently extra monitor to the left side of main monitor I type in my ~/.xprofile as follows:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --left-of LVDS1
```

All information is provided from the Ubuntu wiki here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

Comment: But I do not want to set the settings **permanently**. I just want the configuration to be remembered whenever I return to the external monitor.