# Have to set multiple displays on every start

Tags: ati, multiple-monitors, catalyst

I have a HP DV7 with an ATI graphic card and I have a Samsung monitor connected to the laptop. Every time I turn on the laptop the displays are mirrored and I have to go to the Catalyst control centre (Administrative) and change the displays configuration, I have to do this EVERY TIME I turn on the computer.

[image]

I Didn’t try the solution suggested here ( [Settings for multiple monitors are not stored](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194390/settings-for-multiple-monitors-are-not-stored) ) because it took me a lot to make the graphics card work properly and I want to make sure that I have the right solution ( or the "rightest")

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to go to System Settings > Displays, and the uncheck Mirror Displays option?

Comment: @ Rodrigo, I tried but didn´t work.

Comment: Sorry I can't think how to do it in any other way :/

Comment: Actually now the setting are saved and the dual monitors are displayed properly... the weird thing is that I dnd't do anything new

Comment: O.o Weird now you'd better vote on the best answer to it get a score of 2 and doesn't award the bounty to anyone, so the best voted answer with score fo 2 ou more will own half of the bounty. Or if you think correct award the full bounty to one of them...

Answer (score 2):

some times may be that graphic driver will behave like that, and nothing to worry about this problem. You have to reset or change to default settings of Graphic driver or Screen Settings provided by Ubuntu Operating system.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem which I solved quite easily. Although I've a different video card  it might works for you.

I've set an `.xprofile` file in my home directory with the following content:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1366x768 --primary
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1280x1024 --left-of LVDS1
```

I think the lines are quite self explaining and you could easily modify it so that it fits your situation. A graphical way to setup your screens using [XrandR](http://www.x.org/wiki/Projects/XRandR) is [ArandR](http://christian.amsuess.com/tools/arandr/)

The settings will be applied when you log in.