# How to save monitor configuration on a laptop

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display

How do you save a monitor configuration based on how many displays are available on a laptop?

I have a laptop that I often use with and without an external monitor. When I connect the monitor, Gnome-Shell automatically reconfigures to use the second display, but it always places the laptop's screen to the left. I have it physically located to the right, so I use the Displays dialog to move it. However, this is lost every time I unplug the display or suspend and resume the laptop.

This is similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194390/settings-for-multiple-monitors-are-not-stored) but I don't want to hard-code my Xorg/Xrandr setup to force dual displays because I often use the laptop without a monitor. I just want it to automatically place my laptop's screen to the right whenever I plug in the external monitor.

Edit: Output of `xrandr` with external monitor setup.

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3200 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-0 connected primary 1280x800+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 286mm x 179mm
   1280x800       60.2*+
DP-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 290mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.0     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     59.9  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Can be done. Could you paste (a link to) the output of `xrandr` with your second monitor connected and set up as you want it? You can post the link in a comment, later we can combine it in the question.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, Edited.

Comment: Added my answer. please let me know if you need help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution exists of two parts:

#### 1. create a small script to arrange the screens

You should think of your combined screens as one combined virtual screen, as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/614242/72216).
To arrange two screens into the combined virtual screen, you need to arrange them from left to right. In your case:

to place the left screen on `0,0`:

```
xrandr --output DP-0 --pos 0x0
```

to place the right screen (your build in screen):

```
xrandr --output LVDS-0 --pos 1920x0
```

When we put these two commands in a script:

```bsh
#/bin/bash
xrandr --output DP-0 --pos 0x0
xrandr --output LVDS-0 --pos 1920x0
```

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `set_screen.sh`
- To use it (after the second screen is connected), run the command:

  ```
  /bin/bash /path/to/set_screen.sh
  ```

  or, if you make it executable:

  ```
  /path/to/set_screen.sh
  ```

Now you have two options, you can either:

- add the script to a shortcut key: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command to run the script,

or:

#### 2. Run a script in the background to call the command

As described In the post: [Run script when monitor is connected](https://askubuntu.com/a/630335/72216). 
Replace in the section:

```
#--- set both commands (connect / disconnect) below
connect_command = "gedit"
```

`"gedit"` by the command to run the script that you created in step 1:

```
"/bin/bash /path/to/set_screen.sh"
```

If you add the script in the linked post to your startup applications, you will have your setup to fully automatically arrange your screens if the second monitor is connected.